# Installing packages with pip on my centos server times out with an warnings and error

Tags: python, django, macos, server

This is the error i get. Am using python3

```
pip install django
Collecting django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

Comment: The error you're getting is a timeout error, which is likely due to a network issue.

Comment: Hello, i have switched to different networks but the error still persists. Not sure what the issue could be at this point. Been trying the installation close to a two days now and same error appears regardless of the network.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a proxy server.
you can specify your proxy server with `--proxy` flag.

like this:
`pip install --proxy your_proxy_server django`